# Not able to perform inner join on two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables called **NO2_avg** and **temperature_avg**, I'm trying to join this tables on common column **DATE(`Date Time`)**, but I'm getting following error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"DATE(`Date Time`)" = a2."DATE(`Date Time`)"' at line 4
```

Tables info:

**NO2_avg**

```
+----------------------+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
| Location             | DATE(`Date Time`) | COUNT(*) | avg(NO2)           |
+----------------------+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
| Temple Way           | 2017-09-07        |       24 | 27.305995000000006 |
| Parson Street School | 2017-09-07        |       24 | 32.020833333333336 |
| Fishponds Road       | 2017-09-07        |       24 |             39.125 |
| Wells Road           | 2017-09-07        |       24 | 41.354166666666664 |
| Brislington Depot    | 2017-09-07        |       24 |           23.09375 |
+----------------------+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
```

**temperature_avg**

```
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
| DATE(`Date Time`) | COUNT(*) | avg(Temperature)  |
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
| 2017-09-07        |       48 | 4.791666666666667 |
| 2022-03-04        |       48 | 5.333333333333333 |
| 2022-03-03        |       48 |            7.5625 |
| 2022-03-02        |       44 | 7.090909090909091 |
| 2022-03-01        |       48 | 5.791666666666667 |
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
```

Query that I used :

```
SELECT `avg(NO2)`
FROM
     NO2_avg a1
INNER JOIN Temperature_avg a2 ON a1."DATE(`Date Time`)" = a2."DATE(`Date Time`)";
```

Please help me ...

Comment: You have a column literally named `DATE(\`Date Time\`)`????????

Comment: _Suggestion_ DONT put spaces or special characters like `(` or `)` in table or column names. Also keep all names in lower case, so that does not become an issue when you move the database to another server

Comment: @RiggsFolly now I'm getting this error "[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'a1.Date Time' in 'on clause'".

Comment: Refresh this page an check the comment again

Comment: Start by running an alter table to rename those date columns. mySQL is not very explicit with error messages and there's no need to go looking for trouble!

Comment: @JNevill  due to some data engineering operation my column has "DATE(`Date Time`)" name.... and I tried to change the column name as well but getting error "ALTER TABLE NO2_avg CHANGE DATE(`Date Time`) date_1 Date;" with following query "[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`Date Time`) date_1 Date' at line 1"

Comment: *due to some data engineering operation my column has "DATE(Date Time)" name....* This is a consequence of the absence of aliases for output fields in queries that were used to create tables. That is, the consequences of not knowing the syntax.

Comment: Yeah... with parantheses and backticks and all of this in your column name you'll have to be very careful about escaping and properly encapsulating your column name in backticks. Bill Karwin's answer below shows how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the table was created some time in the past from a SELECT query that didn't define column aliases.

First I would urge you to change the column names to something easier to use. You *can* use columns whose names contain special characters but it's unnecessarily difficult.

MySQL 8.0 supports a RENAME COLUMN option:

```
mysql> alter table NO2_avg 
 rename column `DATE(``Date Time``)` TO date, 
 rename column `COUNT(*)` to count, 
 rename column `avg(NO2)` to avg;
```

Note that you need to delimit the column names, and those that contain literal back-tick characters need to treat those characters as special, either double the back-tick, or use a backslash to escape it.

If you can't rename the columns, then you must delimit the column names with back-ticks and treat literal back-ticks as special as noted above.

Standard SQL supports double-quotes (`"`) as identifier delimiters, but in MySQL, double-quotes are string delimiters unless you set the SQL mode to include [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) or [ANSI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi).

Comment: If you use a version older than MySQL 8.0, you must use `ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE COLUMN...` to change column names. But that requires you to repeat the current column definition including data type and column options. Refer to the documentation for alter table.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation; I couldn't change the column name before, but after following your advice, I was able to do so... and it worked great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use double back tick (``) instead of single back tick (`).

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table NO2_avg ( Location VARCHAR(50),`DATE(``Date Time``)` DATE  , `COUNT(*)` int, `avg(NO2)`  float);

 insert into NO2_avg values('Temple Way'           , '2017-09-07'        ,       24 , 27.305995000000006 );
 insert into NO2_avg values('Parson Street School' , '2017-09-07'        ,       24 , 32.020833333333336 );
 insert into NO2_avg values('Fishponds Road'       , '2017-09-07'        ,       24 ,             39.125 );
 insert into NO2_avg values('Wells Road'           , '2017-09-07'        ,       24 , 41.354166666666664 );
 insert into NO2_avg values('Brislington Depot'    , '2017-09-07'        ,       24 ,           23.09375 );

 create table temperature_avg (`DATE(``Date Time``)` date, `COUNT(*)` int, `avg(Temperature)` float  );

 insert into temperature_avg values('2017-09-07'        ,       48 , 4.791666666666667 );
 insert into temperature_avg values('2022-03-04'        ,       48 , 5.333333333333333 );
 insert into temperature_avg values('2022-03-03'        ,       48 ,            7.5625 );
 insert into temperature_avg values('2022-03-02'        ,       44 , 7.090909090909091 );
 insert into temperature_avg values('2022-03-01'        ,       48 , 5.791666666666667 );
```

Query:

```
 SELECT `avg(NO2)`
 FROM
      NO2_avg a1
 INNER JOIN temperature_avg a2 ON a1.`DATE(``Date Time``)` = a2.`DATE(``Date Time``)`;
```

Output:

| avg(NO2) |
| --- |
| 23.0938 |
| 41.3542 |
| 39.125 |
| 32.0208 |
| 27.306 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f91beefde11e467c1537e7248ca9185)*